# How to add latest photo of photo library to uiimageview using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gallery

Is there a way to add the latest photo of my photo library to an uiimageview?  I've tried nearly everything but nothing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

let last = fetchResult.lastObject

if let lastAsset = last {
  let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
  options.version = .current

  PHImageManager.default().requestImage(
    for: lastAsset,
    targetSize: imageView.bounds.size,
    contentMode: .aspectFit,
    options: options,
    resultHandler: { image, _ in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
      }
    }
  )
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)

    let last = fetchResult.lastObject

    if let lastAsset = last {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .Current
        options.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(
            lastAsset as! PHAsset,
            targetSize: imageView.bounds.size,
            contentMode: .AspectFit,
            options: options,
            resultHandler: { image, _ in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.imageView.image = image
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the code look like in Swift 2? Sorry, but I've never used Swift before

Comment: I will add the Swift 2 version in a minute.

Comment: I've added the Swift 2 version.

Comment: Do you also know how to show a video in a UIView? Because I want something like a photo gallery where i can show the latest videos and photos in a UIView

Comment: You need `MPMoviePlayerController` for this.